# Error When Using Flutter With firebase_auth on Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I'm having a problem with Firebase in Flutter.I followed the instructions from the official Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web):

They are not that complicated, I did them twice to try to solve the problem, so it's unlikely I missed any. This is the code, which as you can see is very simple.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
  FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine on Android, but on the web I get this error that I couldn't find on the internet.

Line:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
```

Error:

```
Expected a value of type 'JavaScriptObject', but got one of type 'Null'.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3 throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 127:3 castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 818:12 cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/classes.dart 652:14 as_C
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_shared/lib/js_util_patch.dart 81:5 getProperty
packages/firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart 314:54 get currentUser
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 167:50 get currentUser
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 264:11 authStateChanges
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 331:40 runBody
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54 runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18 handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44 handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13 _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 647:5 [_completeWithValue] [_completeWithValue] _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 721:7 callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11 _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5 _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7 <fn> _startMicrotaskLoop*
```

Please, if anyone can help me and tell me what could be going on I would really appreciate it.

I tried starting a new flutter project, keeping things simple and following the firebase documentation. No success. Flutter doctor doesn't throw any errors and both dart and flutter seem to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use flutterfire configure to setup firebase? if yes did you check if you have setup the credentials for the web platform in `firebase_options.dart`?

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
```

When you build for Android `currentPlatform` get the Android credentials in `firebase_options.dart`

It does not work for web because FirebaseOptions is probably missing for this plateform.

After updated all the packages, your code is working on my side

```
firebase_core: ^2.25.2
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^5.0.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.15.2
firebase_auth: ^4.17.2

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_web: 2.10.0
  firebase_auth_web: 5.8.13
  cloud_firestore_web: 3.9.0
```

my flutter version

```
Flutter Channel stable, 3.16.7
```

more infos on the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12237#issuecomment-1923346463)

Comment: Greetings! Firstly, I really appreciate your help.

Yes, I have already checked what you say. I ran flutterfire configure and made sure the credentials in firebase_options are correct for "web". I just modified the code in the question because I realised I had put the wrong code. It's the counter example with the firebase initialisation, which works fine. The error appears with FirebaseAuth.

Thank you very much! Have a great day.

Comment: I tried to run with the latest packages but it seems like there is an issue with firebase_core_web https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12253

Comment: I edited my answer with a fix to be able to run the code with the latest version of packages. No issue with your code.